# AndroidPlot : hide some points on the same curve

Tags: android, androidplot

I have an application that displays values on a graph, but some of the values are "undefined" (in a numerical display, dashes are shown instead of the faulty values). I would like to know if it is possible with AndroidPlot to skip some values, resulting in gaps on the same curve.

Thanks for your help.
I can provide you with more info if needed.

Comment: Are you using a line plot?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible; take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210061/is-it-possible-to-hide-points-on-an-androidplot-xyplot/24219257#24219257) for the details on how to implement.