# Is it possible to hide points on an Androidplot XYplot?

Tags: androidplot

1) I have an Androidplot XYPlot and some values are 0 to represent "no data" on that point. Can I hide these points with value "0" from the plot?

2) If I can't hide them, can I make the graph lines going from the previous point, to the 0 value point and to the next point, another color (like red) to show that this is a point "with no data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XYPlot's underlying model is XYSeries which uses Numbers to represent points. If you're implementing your own XYSeries then just return null from getX(i) / getY(i) where i is the index of any "no data" element.

If you're using SimpleXYSeries, then just pass null into the constructor, model or setX/Y method you're using to populate it.

When the plot is drawn, you should see your line(s) broken up where nulls are encountered.

Answer (score -1):

After pondering Nicks answer I got it working:

```
plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

// nums is an array holding different numbers, where some are 0.

Number Nullnumber = null;

SimpleXYSeries series1test;
series1test = new SimpleXYSeries("title");

for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){

    if(nums[j]==0){
        series1test.addLast(j, Nullnumber); // Does not display points for 0 values
        //series1test.addLast(j, nums[j]);  // Displays points for 0 values
    } else {
        series1test.addLast(j, nums[j]);
    }
}

LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
series1Format.configure(getApplicationContext(),
R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_plf1);

plot.addSeries(series1test, series1Format);
```

Comment: I still see points on the lines